# Upload chunked video to Twitter with Oauth Echo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, oauth, httparty

I have a media API (Delegator application) and I'm attempting to allow users of third party applications (Consumer applications) to tweet video via my API on behalf of a user (User), so I'm implementing [Oauth Echo](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/echo). I am able to complete the first step, verifying the user's credentials, so I know my credentials are valid; however, when I go to initialize the upload I get a "Could not authenticate you" error. In the chunked media upload docs, I noticed this section, but it's unclear to me how this applies to performing [chunked media upload](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media#chunkedupload) via Oauth Echo:

> "Because the method uses multipart POST, OAuth is handled a little
>   differently. POST or query string parameters are not used when
>   calculating an OAuth signature basestring or signature. Only the
>   oauth_* parameters are used."

Here's the debug output from my request:

```
opening connection to upload.twitter.com:443... opened starting SSL for upload.twitter.com:443... SSL established <- "POST /1.1/media/upload.json?command=INIT&media_type=video%2Fmp4&total_bytes=2000 HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_nonce=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_signature=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1457492349\", oauth_token=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: upload.twitter.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n" <- ""
-> "HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n"
-> "connection: close\r\n"
-> "content-length: 64\r\n"
-> "content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n"
-> "date: Wed, 09 Mar 2016 03:10:23 GMT\r\n"
-> "server: tsa_a\r\n"
-> "set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A145749302339262531; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 09-Mar-2018 03:10:23 UTC\r\n"
-> "strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519\r\n"
-> "vary: Origin\r\n"
-> "x-connection-hash: 6a4b3c223cca493550d30c3fed750df1\r\n"
-> "x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n"
-> "x-response-time: 7\r\n"
-> "x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"
-> "\r\n" reading 64 bytes...
-> ""
-> "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":32,\"message\":\"Could not authenticate you.\"}]}" read 64 bytes Conn close
=> #[{"code"=>32, "message"=>"Could not authenticate you."}]}, @response=#, @headers={"connection"=>["close"], "content-length"=>["64"], "content-type"=>["application/json; charset=utf-8"], "date"=>["Wed, 09 Mar 2016 03:10:23 GMT"], "server"=>["tsa_a"], "set-cookie"=>["guest_id=v1%3A145749302339262531; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 09-Mar-2018 03:10:23 UTC"], "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=631138519"], "vary"=>["Origin"], "x-connection-hash"=>["6a4b3c223cca493550d30c3fed750df1"], "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-response-time"=>["7"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"]}>
```

I'm making the HTTP requests using the HTTParty gem. Here's what they look like:

```
#IRL I'm getting the following two vars from the user, but for sake of demonstration this is more or less what they'll be
x_auth_service_provider = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
x_verify_credentials_authorization = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXX", oauth_nonce="XXXX", oauth_signature="XXXX", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1457473883", oauth_token="XXXX", oauth_version="1.0"'

response = HTTParty.get(x_auth_service_provider, 
  :headers => {"Authorization" => x_verify_credentials_authorization})

if response.code == 200
  init = HTTParty.post('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json',
    :headers => {"Authorization" => x_verify_credentials_authorization},
    :body => {'command' => 'INIT', 'media_type'=> 'video/mp4', 'total_bytes' => '2000'},
    :debug_output => $stdout)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to make the same request in the dashboard, to get there I went:

1. https://apps.twitter.com/
2. Clicked on my app
3. Clicked "Test OAuth" button (top-right)

First time I've had the same error as you, but I've noticed this:

> Important: This will only be valid for a few minutes.

I've tried to regenerate OAuth signature and after that request went well. So, maybe your auth keys are expired too?